# Elasticsearch php api ssl unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl, elasticsearch

I've been trying to user Elasticsearch PHP API, using on the local elasticsearch server it works perfectly and I can index and search but when I try to do the same on my web server, using like is said in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_security.html#_using_authentication_with_ssl) it give's me the following errors:

```
Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException Object
(
    [message:protected] => No alive nodes found in your cluster
    [primary_port] => 9200
       (...)
        [local_ip] => 192.168.2.4
        [local_port] => 64641
        [error] => SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
        [errno] => 60
```

I've searching all over the internet and tried:
1. Download the latest cacert.pem
2. Go to XAMPP php.ini and add the line curl.cainfo="C:/xampp/php/cacert.pem"
3. Restart xampp and apache.

It did nothing so I think that can be because of the PHP APi of elasticsearch but I don't know what can be.

Feel free to ask for anything.
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I'm testing this on localhost but when I did online via an https connection it gave me the same errors.

Answer (score -1):

[If you use xampp, please read the following article which is pretty clear to understand why this happens and how to solve it](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/196/xampp-wampp-php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate).

Open the php.ini file once again and search for the [curl] area, now we are going to uncomment and change the value of curl.cainfo and openssl.cafile properties.

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo ="C:\xampp\perl\vendor\lib\Mozilla\CA\cacert.pem"

[openssl]
; The location of a Certificate Authority (CA) file on the local filesystem
; to use when verifying the identity of SSL/TLS peers. Most users should
; not specify a value for this directive as PHP will attempt to use the
; OS-managed cert stores in its absence. If specified, this value may still
; be overridden on a per-stream basis via the "cafile" SSL stream context
; option.
openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\perl\vendor\lib\Mozilla\CA\cacert.pem"
```

The path of your certificates may vary, therefore i recommend you to read the article.

Comment: Hi. I've read the article and changed my php.ini as said there but still got the same errors. I didn't have any [curl] area, don't know if that's a problem!?